# Android SQlite Cursor query error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
String Where = "SELECT FROM peopleTable WHERE _id BETWEEN " + i1+ " AND " + i2;
```

Where is the mistake? LogCAT:

```
12-18 16:47:54.497: E/SQLiteLog(2447): (1) near "SELECT": syntax error
12-18 16:47:54.757: E/AndroidRuntime(2447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 16:47:54.757: E/AndroidRuntime(2447): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, persons_name, persons_hotness FROM peopleTable WHERE SELECT FROM peopleTable WHERE _id BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Comment: You are using SELECT inside another SELECT thats why it is giving a Syntax error not because of BETWEEN CLAUSE.

Comment: So How it could be written Please tell me in brief. @VishalKale

Comment: Look at the answer below I have already written there...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
SELECT _id,
persons_name,
persons_hotness FROM
peopleTable WHERE SELECT
FROM peopleTable WHERE
_id BETWEEN 2 AND 4
```

Use this query

```
 SELECT _id,
persons_name,
persons_hotness FROM
peopleTable WHERE
_id BETWEEN 2 AND 4



 db.query("peopleTable",
 new String[] {_id, person_name,                person_hotness},
"WHERE _id BETWEEN 2 AND 4",        null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: So How it could be written Please tell me in Programming Code. @VishalKale